# Android DexClassLoader OF Broadcastreceiver?

Tags: java, android, dex, dexclassloader

Im trying to dynamic load class of BroadcastReceiver and stuck at this problem for over 2 weeks. It driving me crazy and project is on the dead line.

Any help would be appreciate.

I use this code to call the dex class loader:

```
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(dexPath.getAbsolutePath(), optimizedDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), null, getClassLoader() );
                Class<?> dcl;
                dcl = classLoader.loadClass("com.example.mydexbuilddemo.action.UseRun");
                WorkFlow runControl = (WorkFlow) dcl.newInstance();
                runControl.runMyWork(v.getContext());
```

Then the code above call to this class:

```
public class UseRun implements WorkFlow {@Override
public void runMyWork(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Echo.showEcho(context);
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(context, MyOnBootReceiver.class));
}}
```

Then this class UserRun call to MyOnBootReceiver.class

So the DexClassLoader success load the UserRun class but then the UserRun class could not call the MyonBootReceiver.class.

In the logcat, it doesnt return any error or anything after UserRun class executed.

It success show the:

```
Echo.showEcho(context);
```

But then this doesnt load:

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(context, MyOnBootReceiver.class));
```

The MyOnBootReceiver.class content:

```
public class MyOnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "MY TOAST SHOW", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}   }
```

I follow this tutorial to build this project.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29

Am i missing something, in theory this should work

Also here is Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mydexbuilddemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <receiver android:name="com.example.demo2.act.MyOnBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>       


</application>
```

LOG CAT from Shelvin Suggestion (error):

```
 00:20:44.783: D/dalvikvm(6997): ODEX file is stale or bad; removing and retrying (/data/data/com.example.mydexbuilddemo/app_dexout/secondary_dex.dex)
 00:20:44.803: D/dalvikvm(6997): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'secondary_dex.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
 00:20:45.163: D/dalvikvm(6997): DexOpt: --- END 'secondary_dex.jar' (success) ---
 00:20:45.163: D/dalvikvm(6997): DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.mydexbuilddemo/app_dex/secondary_dex.jar': unzip in 19ms, rewrite 360ms
 00:21:09.837: D/dalvikvm(9886): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 84K, 8% free 17207K/18536K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
 00:21:09.877: D/dalvikvm(9886): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 19509K/20844K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 16ms
 00:21:10.017: D/libEGL(9886): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
 00:21:10.017: D/libEGL(9886): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
 00:21:10.017: D/libEGL(9886): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
 00:21:10.077: D/OpenGLRenderer(9886): Enabling debug mode 0
 00:21:15.803: D/GestureDetector(9886): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 11 mFalseSizeCnt:0
 00:21:15.803: D/USE RUN(9886): use my run work 
 00:23:10.225: D/GestureDetector(9886): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 13 mFalseSizeCnt:0
```

Comment: ... does MyOnBootReciver class is registerd as reciver in manifest or from code ?

Comment: Dear, I forgot to mention, i did register it in manifest.

Comment: could you post this part of manifest ?

Comment: Dear, I just edit in the main post with added manifest. Thank you for your time.

Comment: ok, as you see the action filter for this reciver is BOOT_COMPLETED ... as you can see you didn't set this action in your Intent(`new Intent(context, MyOnBootReceiver.class)`) ... this action can be send only by system ... and i'm pretty sure that you wana to call `runControl.runMyWork` from the inside of the onReceive of MyOnBootReceiver rather then the opposite way - you wana call dynamic code(dex lib) on system boot ...

Comment: Dear @Selvin I will try to rewrite the code again and see if that would work. In theory this still work but i could be wrong. I was going to do that route instead after this workflow fail. Thank you for your time, will let you know the result :)

Comment: wait, first try to use custom inetnt filter for this ... `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MY_AWESOME_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>` and then set this action to the intent `Intent in = new Intent(context, MyOnBootReceiver.class); in.setAction("MY_AWESOME_ACTION");  context.sendBroadcast(in);` .... but i'm not sure if this is what you wana achive ...

Comment: @Selvin

I have try your suggestion and it did not work. This is what i done:
in manifest
`<receiver android:name="com.example.demo2.act.MyOnBootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MY_ACTION_CODE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`


this is in userrun


`Log.d("USE RUN", "use my run work ");
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyOnBootReceiver.class);
  intent.setAction("MY_ACTION_CODE");
  context.sendBroadcast(intent);`

It could log my userrun but MyOnBootReceive did not work.

Comment: I attached the log cat in main post. @Selvin
You are right
`<intent-filter>             <action android:name="MY_AWESOME_ACTION" />         </intent-filter>' 
Is not the the solution i want to achive...i need the app to rerun again after device reboot, so i ll try again on MyOnBootReceiver to see..Any suggestion ? :)

Comment: Still have no solution, but i success load dex directly from apk instead dex class. Thank you